# Javascript Calculate the total distance by a loop

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, loops, distance

I got the script that calculates the distance and I spent my coordinates with 2 points ( pos1 , pos2 ) ( both are geolocated ) Then I put a loop that recharges the script every 5/10 seconds and I saved the distance with a LocalStorage out a loop .
Now I want  out of the loop there is a variable that calculates the total distance , or rather that calculates all distances that are passed by the loop.
This is the code:

```
(function(){

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos1 = position.coords.latitude; 
        pos11= position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('latitudine ' + pos1);
        console.log('longitudine ' + pos11);

        //Passano 2 secondi

        setTimeout(function(){
        pos2 = 45.2968571;
        pos22 = 12.034978499999966;
        console.log('latitudine ' + pos2);
        console.log('longitudine ' + pos22);
        alert("Sono passati 2 secondi");
         },2000);

          // Converte in radianti 

         setTimeout(function(){
         if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
         Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
         return this * Math.PI / 180;
            }
          }
          // From Caspar Kleijne's answer ends
          // From cletus' answer starts
         var R = 6371; // km
         var dLat = (pos2-pos1).toRad();
         var dLon = (pos22-pos11).toRad();
         var lat1 = pos1.toRad();
         var lat2 = pos2.toRad();

          var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) *    Math.cos(lat2); 
         var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
         var distance1 = R * c;
         var distance2 = distance1;
         console.log(distance1, distance2);
         alert('hai percorso: ' + distance1 + 'm ');
         var distance2 = localStorage.setItem('key', distance2);

         },2000);

        })
  }   

         setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
         })();

         (function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
        var distanza = localStorage.getItem('key', 'distance2');
        var distanza1 = distanza;
        // here i wont calculate the total distance 
        console.log('prima: ' + distanza + 'n\totale: ' + total);       
        },6000);

         setTimeout(arguments.callee,10000);
         })();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Found Distance between 2 coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517077/javascript-found-distance-between-2-coordinates)

Comment: i 've solve this problem